# Describing $\mathbb{N}$ with multiples of $4\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Suppose we index subsets of the natural numbers in the following way.

$$\begin{matrix} X_2 = 4 \mathbb{N}  &Y_2 = 8\mathbb{N} \\
X_3 = 16\mathbb{N} & Y_3 = 32\mathbb{N} \\
X_4 = 64\mathbb{N} & Y_4 = 128\mathbb{N} \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix}$$

so that generally we have $X_n = 4^{n-1}$ and $Y_n = 2 \cdot 4^{n-1}$. I am wondering how to describe the set

$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty X_n \setminus Y_n$$

Clearly, we have

$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty X_n \setminus Y_n = (4\mathbb{N} \setminus 8 \mathbb{N}) \cup (16 \mathbb{N} \setminus 32 \mathbb{N}) \cup \dots$$

Since $8 \mathbb{N} \supset 16\mathbb{N} \supset 32\mathbb{N} \supset ...$, as soon as we remove $8\mathbb{N}$, the rest of the chain collapses. Then it would appear to be the case that

$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty X_n \setminus Y_n = 4\mathbb{N} \setminus 8 \mathbb{N}$$

Is this sound or have I missed something here?

Comment: Well $16 \notin 4\mathbb{N} \setminus 8\mathbb{N}$ but $16 \in 16\mathbb{N} \setminus 32\mathbb{N}$. You removed $8 \mathbb{N}$ at the start, but then you some of  it back in later.

Comment: @Bagggggggs I see your point. But if we continue this process recursively, how can we write this in set notation?

Comment: What you have is odd multiples of $4$, unioned with odd multiples of $16$, unioned with odd multiples of $64$, etc. It's $\{4,12,16,20,28,36,44,48,52,\ldots\}$. It is not the same as $4\mathbb{N} \setminus 8\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\nu_2(n)$ be the $2$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{N}$. Let $S_k = \{n \in \mathbb{N}  : \nu_2(n) \geq k\}$ Your set is:

$(S_2 - S_3) \cup (S_4- S_5) \cup ... = \cup_{k=1}^\infty (S_{2k} - S_{2k+1})$.

$n \in \cup_{k=1}^\infty (S_{2k} - S_{2k+1})$ iff $n \in S_{2k} - S_{2k+1}$ for some $k \geq 1$, iff $\nu_2(n) \geq 2k , \nu_2(n) < 2k+1$ for some $k \geq 1$, iff $\nu_2(n) = 2k$ for some $k \geq 1$.

Therefore, your set is $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : \nu_2(n)$ is even and at least 2 $\}$